# get all results the same as the first items which have the same id

Tags: java, sql

See this picture first. This is the result I want showing on Web!
[correct result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6NqW.png)

However, I get a different result that shows the same data as the first item
[wrong one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLf8q.png)

For example, this is the wrong one for the top 5 results.

```
Employee Id Crse Id Class Sec   Class Mtg Nbr   Strm    Descr

0010054 006833  01  1   2163    POLYNESIAN DRUM ENSEMBLE

0010054 006833  01  1   2163    POLYNESIAN DRUM ENSEMBLE

0010846 002668  01  1   2163    SOCIAL WELFARE POLICY

0010846 002668  01  1   2163    SOCIAL WELFARE POLICY

0010846 002668  01  1   2163    SOCIAL WELFARE POLICY
```

The result should be

```
0010054 006833  01  1   2163    POLYNESIAN DRUM ENSEMBLE

0010054 006833  01  2   2163    POLYNESIAN DRUM ENSEMBLE

0010846 002668  01  1   2163    SOCIAL WELFARE POLICY

0010846 001672  01  1   2163    NON-GOV PROG DEVELOP

0010846 006423  01  1   2163    SOCIAL RESEARCH METHODS
```

I don't know why the computer only get the first value of each emplid but not every value of whole emplid.

These are the codes I have. Please help me check where goes wrong. Thanks!

Controller

```
private PsInstrClassDao psInstrClassDao;
private PsCurTermDao psCurTermDao;

public void setPsInstrClassDao(PsInstrClassDao psInstrClassDao) {
    this.psInstrClassDao = psInstrClassDao;
}

public void setPsCurTermDao(PsCurTermDao psCurTermDao) {
    this.psCurTermDao = psCurTermDao;
}

@RequestMapping(value = {""}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getFacultyHome(Model model) {

    List<PsInstrClass> facultyList = psInstrClassDao.list();

    model.addAttribute("faculty", facultyList);

    List<PsCurTerm> termList = psCurTermDao.list();

    model.addAttribute("term", termList);

    return "faculty";
}
```

PsInstrClassDao

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Transactional
public List<PsInstrClass> list() {
    EntityManager em = PsEntityManagerFactoryListener.createEntityManager();
    List<PsInstrClass> faculty = null;

    try {
        faculty = em.createQuery("select instr from PsInstrClass instr, PsCurTerm term "
                                + "where instr.strm = term.strm").getResultList();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error getting InstrClass list", e);
    } finally {
        if (em != null) {
            em.close();
        }
    }

    return faculty;
}
```

Jsp

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <td>Employee Id</td>
    <td>Crse Id</td>
    <td>Class Sec</td>
    <td>Class Mtg Nbr</td>
    <td>Strm</td>
    <td>Descr</td>
</tr>
<c:forEach items="${faculty}" var="facultyItem">
    <tr>
        <td>${facultyItem.emplid}</td>
        <td>${facultyItem.crseId}</td>
        <td>${facultyItem.classSec}</td>
        <td>${facultyItem.classMtg}</td>
        <td>${facultyItem.strm}</td>
        <td>${facultyItem.descr}</td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: can you copy the data as text into your question ([edit]) and also describe what's wrong with the data? I see text and numbers but clicking between images doesn't reveal any difference.

Comment: I have revised it. Take a look~